# Class not found: javax/ws/rs/container/AsyncResponse while starting jboss

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jboss, resteasy

I have to setup an existing project on my system (with no support at all). It is using jboss as server and eap and war deployments.

I have created all the wars and ears and have copied these in deployment folder of jboss but when I start the jboss, I get the following error -

```
10:27:44,208 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit.myProjectName.ear"."myProjectName2.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."myProject-core-ear-2.1.0.ear"."myProject-client.war".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "myProject-client.war" of deployment "myProject-core-ear-2.1.0.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [jboss-as-server-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_74]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_74]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_74]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS018757: Error getting reflective information for class com.lhsystems.myProject.server.rest.service.ClientPort with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.myProject-core-ear-2.1.0.ear.myProject-client.war:main" from Service Module Loader
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:72) [jboss-as-server-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:58)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:107)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:92)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [jboss-as-server-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/container/AsyncResponse
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_74]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) [rt.jar:1.8.0_74]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) [rt.jar:1.8.0_74]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:65) [jboss-as-server-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:68) [jboss-as-server-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.container.AsyncResponse from [Module "deployment.myProjectName.ear.myProjectName:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 15 more
```

I am having porblem in finding out the jar for this class. Should it be in my JDK or some third party web service library?
We are using resteasy in the project but I cannot find this class in resteasy jar either.
Note: We are not using Apache CXF.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Note: I have randomly changed the name of my project here, so don't get confused if you see inconsistencies in the project names in error stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using maven build tool for packaging your application?
I guess you've got to include an appropriate 3rd party jar into your build.
For maven it look like

`<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>`

For any other build tools(gradle,SBT) you can visit 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0.1